# Numbers: Possible to transpose Rows and Columns during Import of txt file?

Tags: finder, numbers, text, sort

I have a txt file which has 5,000 data points separated by commas.

i.e. data123,data456,data17,data918,etc,etc

If I open this txt file in Numbers, it creates each item as its own column, whereas I want each item to be its own row.

I can use the Table > Transpose Rows and Columns option, but Numbers is only able to have a maximum of 1,000 columns, and so there are 4,000 points of data that are missing from my spreadsheet using this method.

Is there a way that I can open the txt file in Numbers with the comma separated values each being created as a row instead of a column to begin with?

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### An easy way

Open the Terminal application and navigate to the folder containing your .txt file. If you know how to use `cd`, use that. If you don't then open Finder and click on the folder containing your file and press <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. This will copy the path to the folder to your clipboard. Then in Terminal type, (pasting the clipboard <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> where it says <paste_here>):

```bsh
cd '<paste_here>'
```

and run the following command, replacing <your_file_name> with the name of your file and <new_file_name> for the name you want to give the transposed output.

```bsh
cat <your_file_name> | tr ',' '\n' > <new_file_name>
```

In case you aren't sure what's going on here: 
`cat` takes one or more file names and outputs their contents 
`|` takes the output of the thing on the left and sends it to the thing on the right 
`tr` replaces any instances of the first character (`,` in this case) and replaces it with the second character (`\n` means a new line)

Learning how to use Terminal will help you solve these kinds of problems very easily. If you want to learn more about it, google "unix/linux shell scripting" and the language being used is "bash".

---

### A better way

```bsh
tr ',' '\n' < infile > outfile
```

I gave the first answer because I felt it was easier to understand for someone who is new to shell scripting. But we can optimize this command by using file redirection (command < filename) instead of cat. Cat is an external program, so we should get rid of it in the command if there is no reason to load it. `tr` doesn't accept filename arguments but it does accept standard input. Here we redirect "infile" to standard input (`< infile`) which is read by the command (`tr ',' '\n'`), then we write the output to outfile (> outfile).

You can also write this as: \

```bsh
< infile tr ',' '\n' > outfile
```

I prefer writing it this way because it follows the same order as the commands are executed: 
| Command       | Action                                         |
| ------------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
| `< infile`    | redirect file named "infile" to standard input |
| `tr ',' '\n'` | replace commas with newlines                   |
| `> outfile`   | write standard out to filename "outfile"       |

Comment: Maybe it's worth of mentioning that ```>>``` appends to the file if it exists and ```>``` overwrites. It could also be beneficial to describe the ```<```as well

Comment: Needless use of `cat`! Simply use: `tr ',' '\n' < infile > outfile`

Comment: What a wonderful answer! I would have been happy with just the terminal command but I really appreciate the explanation. I'm familiar with the Terminal, I know how to `cd` where I need to go and to `ls` to look around, but I didn't even know the language was called bash. Now that I know `tr` I can change all sorts of things in txt files! I have grown more powerful in my problem solving. Thank you!

Comment: RE: "The technically word for it is called "unix/linux shell scripting" and the language being used is "bash"." -- It's 'technical' not "technically" and under **macOS** there is no Linux about it! My shell is **zsh**, the default in clean installs since **macOS Mojave**, so the  language being used is is not `bash` if your shell is **zsh**!

Comment: @RanLearns RE: “Now that I know `tr` I can change all sorts of things in txt files! I have grown more powerful in my problem solving.” —  While `tr` is definitely a valuable tool and is excellent at what it does, you may want to look into using `sed` for manipulating text also.